# How to open a PDF file from pc in iframe?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, iframe, filepath

Is this possible? Can I open a PDF file which stored in my computer in an iFrame?

Here's an example from my project:

```
<iframe style="width:960px;height:720px" src="..\..\3C9DED0628F44190ABF92D3C14F14A14-2-D.pdf"></iframe>
```

This code is shows PDF file from project folder. But I need a src like:

```
D:\SCANNEDDOCUMENTS\2\3C9DED0628F44190ABF92D3C14F14A14-2-D.pdf
```

This file is stored in my pc. Can I show this PDF file? And then I want to make some buttons for other PDF files which in same directory. Like in picture:

[image]

When I clicked one of them, the iframe's src will replace other file's path. But first my problem is I can't show a PDF file from local path in iframe. What should I do?

Comment: if you load the page from a `file:///` url, then yes, you could access the local pdf file. if you're loading the page via `http://`, then no, you cannot load local content in a "remote" page.

Comment: Imagine any web page being able to freely access your local files programmatically, it would be a security nightmare. The browser doesn't care if it's showing a local html file or a remote one with the HTTP protocol, that's why it works this way. See Marc B's comment.

Comment: Thank you friends.
MarcB can you help me more about this? How to i use the "src" attribute? 

@JeffNoel Yes my friend you'r right. But now i'm just testing something for my project.In fact there is a table database about documents. And it'll keep the file's path,url,name etc. The real files will be in server. And in future of project there will be scanner for documents and save files. Now i'm just testing something... Thank you also for your comment...